# Django Template - iterating through nested dictionary - too many examples

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have a call to an external data source that successfully returns a dictionary in this format. There can be any number of entries:

```
    {
'0090000': {'status': 'some status', 'modified_date': '2013-08-09T14:23:32Z', 'modified_by': 'John Doe', 'severity': '3 (Normal)', 'created_by': 'Dan Smith', 'summary': "some status", 'created_date': '2013-07-18T21:10:36Z'},
'0060000': {'status': 'some status', 'modified_date': '2013-06-24T03:19:01Z', 'modified_by': 'Jay Johnson', 'severity': '4 (Low)', 'created_by': 'Tony Thompson', 'summary': "some other status", 'created_date': '2012-05-03T17:45:19Z'}...
}
```

I'm pulling this data end using some information gathered in a form. I've read a ton of docs and examples of how to iterate through this and present the data in a template but I can't quite make it work.

My view is as follows:

```
def agenda_detail(request, agenda_id):

    #get the meeting data
    a_data = get_object_or_404(meetingEvent, pk=agenda_id)

    #get the DEE data for the VAT fieldset
    account_id = a_data.account_number.pk

    #get the stored session user/pass
    username = request.session['username']
    password = request.session['password']

    dee_data = onsiteEngineer.objects.filter(account=account_id)

    #now we get the case data from the Portal API
    portal_raw = CustomerInformation()
    customer_data = portal_raw.getOpenCaseInfo(account_id,username,password)

    return render_to_response('agendas/detail.html',{'a_data':a_data, 'dee_data': dee_data, 'customer_data': customer_data.iteritems()}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My template code dealing with this is (I don't care about the html formatting right now, i just want to see the data on the screen:

```
{% for key, value in customer_data.items %}
<p>{{ key }}</p>
{% for info in value %}
    {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

It's showing no data. I've tried multiple combinations (using .items, using iteritems, etc.) but I can't quite get it to work.

All advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `customer_data` is a dictionary, you can just send `'customer_data': customer_data` instead of `'customer_data': customer_data.iteritems()` in the context.

Now in the template, try this:

```
{% for key, value in customer_data.items %}
    <p>{{ key }}</p>
    {% for k, v in value.items %}
        {{ k }}: {{ v }} <br/>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I also noticed an error on my part, but this example works exactly as expected. Thanks!!